# How can i get ALL the process modules in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

I know that there is a process.Modules list in System.Diagnostics that contains some process modules but I got some troubles with it because I can't find some dlls here:

```
Process process = Memory.GetProcessByName("csgo");

foreach (ProcessModule pm in process.Modules) 
    Console.WriteLine(pm.ModuleName);
```

[image]

So I was looking for a solution to make it work, and I found something interesting in pinvoke.net, but it also didn't work:

```
var snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(SnapshotFlags.Module, (uint)process.Id);

MODULEENTRY32 mod = new MODULEENTRY32() { 
    dwSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MODULEENTRY32)) 
};

if (!Module32First((IntPtr)snapshot, ref mod))
    return;

do { Console.WriteLine(mod.szModule); } while (Module32Next((IntPtr)snapshot, ref mod));
```

[image]

Then I searched for the implementation of the same code in C ++, and it worked

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <TlHelp32.h> 
#include <string> 
#include <sstream> 

using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(0x00000008, a);
    MODULEENTRY32 mod;
    mod.dwSize = sizeof(mod);
    if (!Module32First(snapshot, &mod))
        return 0;
    do { cout << mod.szModule << endl; } while (Module32Next(snapshot, &mod));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

So my questions are: what is the difference between the second and third variants and how can I make it work in C #? I also tried to use OpenProcess() from user32.dll and GetModuleHandle() from kernel32.dll but it did not work.

Comment: Is the C# code 64 bit and the C++ code 32 bit?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the `W` versions of both `Module32FirstW` and `Module32NextW` and `MODULEENTRY32`? You need `MODULEENTRY32W`.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers like `0x8`, use `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE`. You should however use `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32` and compile your program in 64 bit mode to get both 32 bit and 64 bit modules.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thanks!!! It works!!! How can i mark ur answer as a right one or rate u?

Comment: Please post an answer yourself with the information what exactly the problem was and how you fixed it. I don't need any rewards. Thanks

Comment: @KobayashiKanna I'm curious - what _was_ the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must compile your code as x64 and run as administrator to get all the modules.

Alternatively use this as your snapshot type:

`TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32`

and here is what CreateToolHelp32Snapshot() module looping looks like in C#:

```c#
const Int64 INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1;
[Flags]

private enum SnapshotFlags : uint
{
    HeapList = 0x00000001,
    Process = 0x00000002,
    Thread = 0x00000004,
    Module = 0x00000008,
    Module32 = 0x00000010,
    Inherit = 0x80000000,
    All = 0x0000001F,
    NoHeaps = 0x40000000
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct MODULEENTRY32
{
    internal uint dwSize;
    internal uint th32ModuleID;
    internal uint th32ProcessID;
    internal uint GlblcntUsage;
    internal uint ProccntUsage;
    internal IntPtr modBaseAddr;
    internal uint modBaseSize;
    internal IntPtr hModule;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    internal string szModule;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    internal string szExePath;
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool Module32First(IntPtr hSnapshot, ref MODULEENTRY32 lpme);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool Module32Next(IntPtr hSnapshot, ref MODULEENTRY32 lpme);

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool CloseHandle([In] IntPtr hObject);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(SnapshotFlags dwFlags, IntPtr th32ProcessID);

public static IntPtr GetModuleBaseAddress(IntPtr procId, string modName)
{
    IntPtr modBaseAddr = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(SnapshotFlags.Module | SnapshotFlags.Module32, procId);

    if (hSnap.ToInt64() != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MODULEENTRY32 modEntry = new MODULEENTRY32();
        modEntry.dwSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MODULEENTRY32));

        if (Module32First(hSnap, ref modEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (modEntry.szModule.Equals(modName))
                {
                    modBaseAddr = modEntry.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnap, ref modEntry));
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);

    return modBaseAddr;
}
```